# Dealing with GAMS error: A suffix is missing

Tags: error-handling, gams-math

I am solving a model in GAMS. When running the optimzation model I want to save the optimal solution in a new varable. The heart of the code looks like this:

```
variables
   xSave(t) 'saving the value of x at optimum'
   x(t)     'variable';

 SOLVE mymodel MINIMIZE fx Using NLP;
 DISPLAY x.l;
```

When I exit at this point I can see that I have a solution; so the optimazation problem works fine!

I am trying to save the value of `x` in a new variable `xSave` and I have tried two methods:

*Method1:*

```
xSave(t)=x.l(t)
```

*Method1:*

```
loop(t, xSave(t)=x.l(t) ) ;
```

Both methods are returning the same error message:

> A suffix is missing

**What should I do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a suffix on xSave as well as it is a variable, i.e.

```
xSave.l(t) = x.l(t);
```